# If statement taking default value of argument even when given a different value

Tags: python, function, sqlite

While trying to test contextlib.closing(), I created this test code:

```
from contextlib import closing
import sqlite3

def query(SQL, inputs=None):
    print(inputs)
    with closing(sqlite3.connect("test.db")) as con:
        with closing(con.cursor()) as cur:
            if inputs is None:
                cur.execute(SQL)
                print("NO INPUT")
                return None
            else:
                return cur.execute(SQL, inputs).fetchall()

print(query("""
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (
        ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        field1 INTEGER,
        field2 TEXT
    );
"""))

number = input("TEXT")
text = input("TEXT2")

query(f"""
    INSERT INTO test(field1, field2) 
    VALUES(?,?);
    """, (number, text))

print(query("SELECT * FROM test"))
```

It checks whether the query has inputs (such as a SELECT query) or whether it doesn't (such as a CREATE TABLE query). The issue I'm encountering is that the final print statement always prints None regardless of the inputs I enter.

I added `print("NO INPUT")` to the if block to see if the issue was to do with that and found that it always printed when the INSERT query ran. This told me it was not to do with the SQL itself but the selection logic. I also added `print(inputs)` to see if the issue was that the inputs parameter wasn't taking entered values and remained as None, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: Why do you assume that a query with no inputs is not a SELECT query?

Comment: You have this backwards. The `SELECT` query may return something interesting (like the results of the select), while the `INSERT` query does not.

Comment: Your `INSERT` query has inputs, but you can't fetch results from an INSERT. OTOH your `SELECT` query has no inputs, so you don't call `fetchall()`.

Comment: Set `inputs=()`, and there is no need to distinguish between parameterized and non-parameterized queries. `cur.execute("SELECT ...", ())` is valid.

Comment: You're also missing `con.commit()`.

Comment: I thought using a with statement autocommits? @Barmar

Comment: `closing()` just closes the connection, I don't think that commits anything.